# How can I create js array from json object returned from php?

Tags: php, associative-array, json, extjs4.2

Javascript has this fin line of code that alerts you what type of object you are working with.
It is the following:

```
alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj))
```

So, I am working with **`php`** and **`js - extjs 4.2`**, and looking for a way to pass an `associative array` created by php to java by using **`json_encode()`**. So I did the following:

```
<?php echo json_encode($some_array); ?>

Ext.Ajax.request(
{
    url: 'php/parse.php?id='+buttonText,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) 
    {
        //var obj = response;
        var obj = response.responseText;
        alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj));                    
    },
    failure: function(response) 
    {
        alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

The php part of the code is in `parse.php` file as you can see from js code. When I alert the obj, it shows a string of json encoded php array. And js says that **obj** is a **`string object`**. If I keep the commented line **without responseText**, js alerts that **`obj is an Object`** but does not say what type (guessing json type).

What i am trying to achieve, **is to have a legit js array that will get that php array from response** (response is the param. in the function). Thanks

**EDIT :** my php array structure

```
array
(
    'vars' => array( 
                   [0] => 'name' => '1', 'value' => 2
                   [1] => ... )
    'file' => array(
                   [0] => 'name' => 'aaa.aa'
                   [1] => ...)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to **parse** a string of JSON-encoded data into Javascript objects.

The built-in `JSON.parse` function does exactly that.

Comment: So if I do "var arr = JSON.parse(obj)", I will get an js array?

Comment: Remember that JavaScript differentiates between a numerically indexed array (Array) and and associative array (Object).  If you want the former, your JSON should look like `["item1","item2"]`. If you want an associative array, the JSON can look like: `{"key1":"item1","key2":"item2"}`.  To answer your question, you may get an Array or Object depending on the syntax of `obj`.

Comment: I am going to edit the array struct that will be echoed by php above, can you answer to it based on the struct...thanks alot

Comment: @Brian: `JSON.parse` will return Javascript arrays or objects based on whatever the JSON _is_.  Use your debugger (or `console.log`) to see what it returns.